# Adding repetitive headers using the podofo library

Tags: c++, pdf, podofo

Trying to add a text heading to a multi page PDF report created using the pofodo PDF library. Cant seem to find a function for doing this in the API documentation for pofodo. I'm trying to see if there is a function that can add a document wide header (repetitive text heading on each page ).

I can just add text and set to to a different font to make it come off as a heading / header. What I'm trying to see is if there is way of adding a document wide header just with one api call.